# Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown is not stopping when key is not pressed

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to learn XNA game programming, and following along with the tutorial by *John Sonmez* on Pluralsight (a Pong game clone). Here is the code that detects if the left/right key is being pressed so that we can move the paddle:

```cs
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        Velocity = new Vector2(0, -0.5f);

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        Velocity = new Vector2(0, 0.5f);

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

This code works, BUT... the `Keyboard` state never seems to clear. That is to say, if I press the left or right key, even just a quick tap one time, then the paddle just keeps moving as if I'm holding the key down. I'm not holding the key down. I also just loaded this PC "clean" so there is pretty much just Windows (it's Windows 8, if that makes a difference) and Visual Studio and Monogame installed. So there are no competing keyhandlers or anything like that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the else, which makes it 0.
What you're doing now is setting the velocity to 0.5 each time it is down, but never change it back.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```cs
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Velocity = Vector2.Zero;

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        Velocity = new Vector2(0, -0.5f);

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        Velocity = new Vector2(0, 0.5f);

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

In this way you reset your `Velocity` vector when no key is pressed.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually how I fixed it. I knew I was too stuck in the video to see what was going on. (On a side note, I downloaded the code from the Pluralsight website, and it matched what I had at the time, and had the same problem.)

Comment: Your problem was that you are setting a velocity. If you change your code to add a Vector2 to a Position (instead of Velocity) each time a key is pressed your code would be correct.